# React dynamic route doesn't work in build or when deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm having trouble getting a React route to work when running the build version of the app, or when I deploy it on Render. Here are my routes:

```
<Route path="/" element={userID ? <Home /> : <Login />} />
<Route path="/register" element={userID ? <Home /> : <Register />} />
<Route path="/forgotPassword" element= {userID ? <Home /> : <ForgotPassword /> } />
<Route path="/resetPassword/:id/:token" element={userID ? <Home /> : <ResetPassword /> } />
```

All of these routes work fine when I run in dev mode with `npm run start`. However, when I run them in build mode or when deployed on Render, the "resetPassword" route does not work, all other routes still work fine. For resetPassword though, the page just says "Cannot GET /resetPassword/123/456" for example. This route is generated on the backend and then sent in an email, but I don't think that should make a difference.

I tried going into package.json and adding "homepage": "." or "./", even tried setting it to "http://localhost:3000" to see if it fixed build mode. It did not. What's the issue here?

Also, on my server I have this code, not sure if this needs to change: `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, there were a few things wrong here.

First, on my server.js backend file, I had to add this to catch all non static requests to redirect to the react app's index.html file. Add your own path for the react build's index.html file:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
});
```

Also, within that index.html file, I had to add the following:

```
<base href="/" />
```

These two together fixed the issue.